# the function of "the origin " in the sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence, context

Consider the following sentence:

> A shell mound exhibition center was constructed in 2002 to
>   reproduce the distribution of the relics and lifestyle of the
>   Neolithic age, **the origin**, distribution of relics and
>   characteristics of the shell mound in the area and the excavation site
>   are to be used as a learning center about historical relics by
>   students.

I think I need to separate the sentence and I can't get why "the origin" is used in the middle of the sentence. Isn't it a bit awkward ?

and what would "reproduce the distribution of the relics" mean in the sentence? I can't get the concept of it.

I want to separate the sentence like this:

> The shell mound exhibition center was constructed in 2002 to reproduce
>   the distribution of the relics and lifestyle of the Neolithic age. The
>   distribution of relics and characteristics of the shell mound in the
>   area and the excavation site are to be used as a learning center about
>   historical relics by students.

Would it get better ?

Comment: Where is that originally from?

Comment: you mean the relics ??

Comment: @Sam Where is *the sentence* from?

Comment: On the leaflet I took in the museum

Comment: I have found it in online too, check out the shell mound section. https://www.knmm.or.kr/eng/Menu05_About/about_04.aspx#img1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Korean - you can make use of [its Korean counterpart page](https://www.knmm.or.kr/eng/Menu05_About/about_04.aspx#) to get the meaning clarified. From what I can see:

- 'reproduce the distribution of the relics' simply means to say 'replicate the old days to show how the relics were dispersed in the area'.
- 'the origin' relates to the second part: 'the origin and the distribution of the relics...' means to add 'where the relics come from' in the description.